# Unity color wont assign to ball or what it should be painting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors

```
private Color solveColor;

void Start()
{
    Color[] colors = { Color.cyan, Color.red, Color.green, new Color(245, 195, 29), Color.yellow, Color.magenta };

    int lengthOfColors = colors.Length;
    int solveColor = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, lengthOfColors);

}
private void start()
{
    GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = solveColor;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Set the balls speed when it should travel
    if (isTraveling) {
        rb.velocity = travelDirection * speed;
    }

    // Paint the ground
    Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position - (Vector3.up/2), .05f);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < hitColliders.Length)
    {
        GroundPiece ground = hitColliders[i].transform.GetComponent<GroundPiece>();

        if (ground && !ground.isColored)
        {
            ground.Colored(solveColor);
        }
```

The above code is supposed to pick one color from the colors array and assign it to both the ball and balls painting ability (whenever the ball collides with the ground it changes its color) however the paint the ball leaves is always black and the ball itself is always orange (pretty sure the ball color is coming from its default). I can't figure out why this is happening any help is very appreciated.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you provided, nowhere do you set the material color of the ball again aside from `Start`. If you want to have the particles behind the ball leave different colors, you will need to instantiate a new instance of the material. The reason for this is because materials in Unity are default shared between all instances of that particular material.

All of this info and a bit more can be found on the [`Material`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-material.html) docs page.

As you have a fixed size of colors you are using, I would instead create 6 new materials and make an array of materials instead. Now, instead of randomly picking a color, pick a material and assign it to the ball or your new instanced painting ability. I am also confused as to why you are placing your array of colors inside of your `Start` function. It would be localized to that function only then. You also appear to have two `Start` functions, which is odd. One being the Monobehaviour `Start` and another `start`. Unless that is intended, your second `start` will not be run unless you call it.

Now to get to the solution I was talking about.

```
// assign these in the inspector to your new materials
[SerializeField] private List<Material> materials = new List<Material>();

private MeshRenderer meshRender;

private void Start()
{
    meshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    
    // set our first random Material
    SetNewMaterialColor();
}

private void SetNewMaterialColor()
{
    meshRenderer.material = GrabNewMaterial();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Set the balls speed when it should travel
    if (isTraveling) {
        rb.velocity = travelDirection * speed;
    }
    
    // Paint the ground
    Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position - (Vector3.up/2), .05f);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < hitColliders.Length)
    {
        GroundPiece ground = hitColliders[i].transform.GetComponent<GroundPiece>();
    
        if (ground && !ground.isColored)
        {
            // change this from a color to a material instead
            ground.Colored(meshRenderer.material);
            
            // set a new material to your main object
            SetNewMaterialColor();
        }
    }
}

private Material GrabNewMaterial()
{
    return materials[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, materials.Count)];
}
```

You will need to change your `Colored` function to take in a `Material` instead of a `Color`. If you want the implementation to be more dynamic, you can instead create an instance of your material and set the color dynamically, but as you have a fixed size of colors I do not think you need to do that.

Edit: The one other option which involves creating a new shader would be to utilize `[PerRendererData]` meaning each object for a property field is rendered individually. I would go with the previous option as either option using shaders or instanced materials is a bit more complex.

You would need to use a [`MaterialPropertyBlock`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html) and can then assign the color when you want. It would look something like

```
public void SetNewColor()
{
    // create a new material property block
    MaterialPropertyBlock tmpBlock = new MaterialPropertyBlock();
    
    // grab the current block from our renderer
    meshRender.GetPropertyBlock(tmpBlock);
    
    // set our changes to the block
    tmpBlock.SetColor("_Color", YourColorHere);
    
    // now apply our changes
    tmpRend.SetPropertyBlock(tmpBlock);
}
```

And you would need to create a new shader that laters the `Main Color` property by using the `PerRendererData` attribute.

```
Properties
    {
        [PerRendererData]_Color("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
...
```

Also, one other question I have is why you are using `Physics.OverlapSphere` instead of just an `OnCollisionEnter`? Or if your game is 2D, then `OnCollisionEnter2D` and let the physics engine handle how collisions work, then just change the colors when the collision occurs?

**Edit:** Here are the answer to your questions - let me know if you have more.

> In the line "[SerializeField] private List materials = new
> List();" which section do I need to replace with the
> materials and how?

The line as is is fine. By using `[SerializeField]` it exposes this list to the editor. You will want to create several new duplicate materials that use your 6 different colors. Instead of setting the colors, you will be setting materials now. What I mean by inspector and editor is you can find the object that has this script on it in Unity, select it (it must be a Prefab or in the scene), then a tab of the Unity editor will populate with information about this object. Find the script portion and find the field `materials`. There should be a drop-down arrow, click it and set the number to `6` (or however many material swaps you want). Now create 6 new materials with your colors and drag them into the boxes that appeared.

> Would it be something like writing "./Materials/Ball 1" in the () for
> example?

Nope! You would be assigning this data in the inspector, so the data would be stored in the list without referencing them in code.

> And I'm not sure how to assign this to my ball using "[SerializeField]
> private GameObject paintObject = null;"

Similarly, this would appear in the inspector. However, remove this line as I misunderstood your original question and accidentally left this in. I assumed that your paint object was a Prefab that you were spawning after the ball bounced, not the ground that you were changing the color of.

> I get the error "Argument 1: cannot convert from
> 'UnityEngine.Material' to 'UnityEngine.Color'"

Yep! So as I mentioned in the comments, your function call to your paint object is most likely currently taking a `Color` parameter. As I changed your implementation to instead directly set `Material`, you will need to change how that function signature. Specifically the line:

```
ground.Colored(meshRenderer.material);
```

You have some object `ground` that is of type `GroundPiece` and has a function called `Colored`. I assume it currently look something like:

```
public void Colored(Color color){...}
```

You want to change this instead to:

```
public void Colored(Material mat{...}
```

After changing it, instead of changing the ground's color in this script, you would change its material directly. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your advice, I read through it and the materials link you provided and just a few more questions (sorry if its easy stuff I've only been using unity and c# for about 2 days so I'm really not sure about it still). In the line "[SerializeField] private List<Material> materials = new List<Material>();" which section do I need to replace with the materials and how? Would it be something like writing "./Materials/Ball 1" in the () for example? And I'm not sure how to assign this to my ball using "[SerializeField] private GameObject paintObject = null;" because

Comment: this script is being attached to the ball itself (it also controls its movement on swipe etc). My last question is why do I get the error "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Material' to 'UnityEngine.Color'". Again thank you so much for all your help and I'm sorry if these are easy/obvious fixes. Have a great day!

Comment: No worries! I will answer your questions in order as an updated part of my answer.

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with the inspector, it looks something like [this](https://answers.unity.com/storage/temp/51357-1.png). Once you click on the drop-down and increase the count, you will be able to drag in `Material` references to it.

Comment: Thank you so much I never would've figured this out without your help. It works perfectly now thank you for your patience and explanations I really appreciate it this is exactly what I was looking for!